# Pagination not working correctly when using categories and Transcribe

Tags: categories, pagination, transcribe

I'm using Transcribe and I'm having an issue with pagination on my blog.

When I filter by category the pagination links are also counting entries from my other languages.

It works fine without the category filter, here is the entries tag:

```
    {exp:channel:entries
    channel="blog"
    dynamic="no"
    paginate="bottom"
    limit="3"
}
```

This gives me this url: /blog/ and /blog/P3

My tag for listing Category entries is

```
    {exp:channel:entries
    channel="blog"
    dynamic="yes"
    paginate="bottom"
    limit="3"
}
```

I have had to switch "dynamic" to "yes" so EE can show the correct entries.

This give me this url: /blog/category/category-name/ and EE displays the correct entries.

I'm getting pagination even though there are only 3 entries in this language, clicking the pagination take me to an empty listing as Transcribe knows not to show other language entries.

If I remove posts in the other languages from the category the pagination does not show. This confirms to me that the Pagination is counting all entries across all languages, even though the entries themselves are not displayed.

I cannot seem to find a way to display the category entries and get pagination to work.

Any ideas?

Cheers
Darren

Comment: add the paginate_base param, see if this helps any. if not we can go from there.

Comment: do you have category names in url enabled?

Comment: Tried adding paginate base as below: paginate_base="blog/category/{segment_3}"

Comment: category names in urls are enabled, this is working as I can list my entries from categories fine. Its just the pagination issue with entries from other languages been included in the overall entry count.

Comment: do you have the lang prefix in the url?

Comment: Used the same method from the Transcribe FAQs for Prev/Next Entry linking, limiting to entry_ids, this works.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this if you limit the entries outputted to those in the language you are in.

You can do this by adding the 'entry_id' parameter and using a Transcribe tag to output all the entry ids

The refined channel tags is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="blog"
dynamic="yes"
paginate="bottom"
limit="3"
entry_id='{exp:transcribe:entry_ids channel="blog"}'
parse="inward"}
```